# Kubernetes ftp deploy simple example

Tags: kubernetes, ftp, proftpd, vsftpd

Last week I was trying to deploy ftp in K8s but I cound not deploy it. 
I tried to find some simple example but I only found very hard examples.

Can you give me some simple examples?

Comment: https://github.com/aledv/kubernetes-ftp   might be useful

Comment: Another [example](https://gist.github.com/jujhars13/1e99cf110e5df39d4ae3c7fef81589f8)